# Simple test SVG with 2 strokes in a path are different widths

Tags: svg

There are many forms of this question on SO but none of them seem to cover this simple case: I have 2 lines in an SVG and they are drawn with different stroke widths. I've tried multiple tricks from the other posts but nothing seems to work. There is something simple here that I'm missing.

Here is the simplest form of this bug I can reproduce:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg width="120px" height="410px" viewBox="0 0 120 410">
    <g id="rooms" stroke-width="8" stroke="#979797">
        <path d="M0,0 L40,0"></path>
        <path d="M0,20 L40,20"></path>
    </g>
</svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the drawing result:
[image]

I've also created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scottjenson/bdqu89e2/), trying to use the other SO articles suggestions, with no effect. I've also tested this in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox and all have the same result.

I'm a little stunned that such a simple thing has this type of drawing bug. I must be missing something very obvious. In the fiddle I also try using LINE instead of PATH and that DOES work properly. This appears to be related to paths.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was indeed a noob mistake. It wasn't clear that the width of a stoke is centered on the line. All paths drawn along the edge of my viewBox were effectively clipped.

TL;DR: Don't draw from 0,0